# Texture undeclared identifier in OpenGL es

Tags: opengl-es, glsl

I try to compile this shader:

```
varying vec2 TexCoords;
varying vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D text;
uniform vec3 textColor;

void main()
{    
    vec4 sampled = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, texture(text, TexCoords).r);
    color = vec4(textColor, 1.0) * sampled;
}
```

This is for OpenGL es. The errors which I get:

```
ERROR: 0:2: 'vec2' : No precision defined for this type
ERROR: 0:3: 'vec4' : No precision defined for this type
ERROR: 0:6: 'vec3' : No precision defined for this type
ERROR: 0:10: 'texture' : undeclared identifier
ERROR: 0:10: invalid function call
```

Note that it compiles on OpenGL 3.3, but fails on es.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [OpenGL ES Shading Language 1.00 Specification -  4.5.3 Default Precision Qualifiers](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.00.pdf#page=41&zoom=100,153,549):

> The fragment language has no default precision qualifier for floating point types. Hence for float, floating
> point vector and matrix variable declarations, either the declaration must include a precision qualifier or
> the default float precision must have been previously declared.

Therefore you must add a precision qualifiere. e.g:

```c
precision mediump float;
```

---

The overloaded functional `texture` was introduced in GLSL ES 3.00, but it is not supported in GLSL ES 1.00. You have to use the function `texture2D`:

<s>`vec4 sampled = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, texture(text, TexCoords).r);`</s>

```c
vec4 sampled = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, texture2D(text, TexCoords).r);
```